# How can I rename music videos on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, folders, ios

I want to find some music videos and rename them, but I can't figure out how to do that?

I am using iPhone 4S - iOS 5.0.1 - a jailbroken phone and using iFile And iFunBox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to rename the title of the Music video. The workaround would be this (NOTE: This does involve using a paid Cydia package, Bridge ($1.99)):

- Open Cydia and search for "Bridge". Buy it, install it, respring.
- Navigate to `/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/Music` via iFile (or SSH Client of choice)

  - This is where your music, music videos and movies are stored on iOS.
- Tap on the gear icon in the left lower corner, go to File Manager > Search Format and change it to Wildcard if not already selected.
- Go back to File Manager and turn on "Song Titles" if not already on. Press Done in the upper right corner.
- Swipe up to reveal the search field, select "Hierarchy" and type "*.m4v"

  - NOTE: If your video files are not M4V, then you would type their extension in it's place eg. *.AVI or *.MP4.
  - This should search all of the subfolders (F01, F02…) for any video files.
- Unfortunately iTunes names them things like "AAWA.mp3", that is why we turned on song titles. It should display the title above the file name for the video.
- Once you find the file, note it's location in case you mess up the next step:
- Long press over it and choose "Select".
- Tap the clipboard in the lower right corner and select copy.
- Navigate to `/var/mobile/Documents/Downloads` and paste the video.
- Go to Bridge on the home screen and navigate to `/var/mobile/Documents/Downloads`
- Choose the video file to import, on the info page select "Music Video" and choose a title for it.
- Tap import and you should be all set! :-)

It is quite a long and convoluted way to rename a video file, but it is possible (sort of!).

Answer (score 0):

If you have jailbroken your iPhone, I would recommend installing openSSH.

I don't know how to locate the files using iFile or iFunbox, but you install openSSH you can log onto your device using a SSH/FTP client, and your movie files should be placed at:

```
/user/media/dcim/
```

I use WinSCP (http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) to FTP to my iPhone.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer | i checked it with both WinSCP and iFunBox and that folder was empty (/user/media/dcim/) but i have two music files in my vedeos area(i got them with celeste bluetooth).i want to transfer them to iTunes And Rename them. also i want to find them (folder location)

Comment: any other location?

Comment: any body home? is this area active? no comment, no new answer...

Comment: hello....
still no help...